# Need to Clean my Oracle Unbreakable Linux

Tags: linux

My Oracle Unbreakable Linux was restarted unexpectedly several times so i found that due to some virus attacks (SFEWFESFS) it gets restarted so i just delete this file but after some time it comes again

My Mission to Do

1. Stop process names as "sfewfesfs" its running (Scree attached screen shot)
2. Delete or rename rc.local to remove to run sfewfesfs at boot time
3. Remove Link S99local pointing towards rc.local or Delete S99local because it runs rc.local

All screen shots are attached

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oracle Breakable would be a more honest description... Assume the machine is completely compromised. Reinstall and restore your data from a known clean backup.

Comment: but i want to clean as much possible for this machine

Comment: Next time the machine does something weird, you'll never know if it's a bug or because of a compromised binary you didn't find first time.  It's safer to trash it and start again.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lot of junk on `/etc/rc.local`.  You should be worried of the content of all these randomly-named executable files in `/tmp`, not just the first one.

Additionally, none of the 3 points you listed makes sense.  The commentators to your post gave you sensible advice: Nuke the machine from orbit, then reinstall from a clean media.  That's the best thing to do.